# Encapsulate c++ Random Number Generator

Tags: c++, random, encapsulation

I'm building something that requires me to

```
template<D>
class DistributionAdapter {
public:
    /**
     * @return number generated by the distribution function.
     */
    virtual D operator()(RANDOM_NUMBER_GENERATOR& rng) = 0;
};
```

RANDOM_NUMBER_GENERATOR is supposed to represent the class of random number generator in c++, either std::random_device or a pseudo random number generator. Can someone tell me how should I approach this, I don't know if random number generator in c++ have a common base type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section § 26.5.1.3 of the standard describes the requirements for random number **generators**.

In particular, a generator must support the function call operator :

> g() T Returns a value in the closed interval [ G::min() , G::max() ] .
>   amortized constant

So, although there is no base class shared by every single generator, the standard guarantees that the `operator()` will be present in each of them : you can call `rng()` in your function.

Comment: Then which type do we enforce in parameter? This solution doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but here is a fairly easy to use function returning uniformly distributed random integers within a particular range.

```
#include <random>

// random number generator from Stroustrup: 
// http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-random
int rand_int(int low, int high)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re {};
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;
    static Dist uid {};
    return uid(re, Dist::param_type{low,high});
}
```